# Multiple has_many: :through relationship to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a model for `Sellers` and they own `games` and `unlimited_games` which can be bought by other `players`. I want to pull all the purchases for a specific `seller`. My model when I only had `games` was:

```
class Seller
  has_many :purchases, through: :games, dependent: :destroy
end

class Purchase
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game
  has_many :purchases
  belongs_to :coach
end
```

## Updated Models

```
def UnlimitedGame
  has_many :purchases
  belongs_to :coach
end

def Purchase
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :unlimited_game
end
```

And I could do a `@seller.purchases` to get all purchases for that seller. Now I want to extend the same feature to include all `unlimited_games`

So that doing `@seller.purchases` includes both `unlimited_games` and `games`. I tried doing:

`has_many :purchases, through: :games, dependent: :destroy, class_name: :purchases`

`has_many :purchases, through: :unlimited_games, dependent: :destroy, class_name: :purchases`

Comment: How do you image rails is supposed to know when `purchases` refers to `games` and when `purchases` refers to `unlimited_games`?

Comment: I can differentiate it using different names when I want them specifically like `unlimited_games_purchases` or `games_purchases` but can I do `purchases` to get all of the `games` which includes both `games` and `unlimited_games`

Comment: And what would that look like, given that you've defined `purchases` and then immediately redefined `purchases`?

Comment: I know that won't work, but that's exactly part I'm unsure about. It's possible that there might be a way to include multiple associations to get the same `table`. I can't find a way to do it right now but I was hoping that this question would get me an answer for the same

Comment: What is the difference between `game` and `unlimited_game`?

Comment: Hi @annon, `Purchase` also belongs_to `unlimited_games`?

Comment: What is an `UnlimitedGame`? This seems like an issue with your design pattern rather than an issue with how to build this association.

Comment: @jvillian They're just two different types of games but they've separate models because they're optionally available to different user types

Comment: @engineersmnky I added the information for the new models

Comment: @anonn023432 my question was actually more directed at what differentiates an `UnlimitedGame` from a `Game` and why should they be separate models? If I am purchasing unlimited games from a `Seller` to me that means I have access to all of there games through a purchase. Since this clearly relates to a purchase and not the type of game I am purchasing it should be attributed to a `Purchase` in some fashion rather than to some different form of `Game` unless I misunderstand what an `UnlimitedGame` is.

Comment: @engineersmnky sorry for the confusion. `UnlimitedGame` and `Game` are two different types of games. `Game` is created by the seller and all users can purchase it whereas `UnlimitedGame` is created by the `admins` and assigned to some `sellers`. A specific group of `Users` can then buy these `UnlimitedGame` type game.

Comment: seems that should just be a category of `Game` then all `Purchase`s are `Buyer` => `Purchase` => (`Game` => `Seller`) and the category of the `Game` is ("Unlimited", or "Seller Created") terminology TBD by you. It cleans up your relationships and will allow for extensibility if you decide to add a new `Game` type later

Comment: @engineersmnky the reasoning behind creating a separate model was that `Game` uses really old legacy code which is inefficient and it would take a long time to include `UnlimitedGame` to it. So, for now, we were going to create a different model then later merge it with `Game` after it's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Supussing `unlimited_games` is not a model on itself and instead is a scope on the `games` model, then you could do something like this in the `Seller` model:

```
def unlimited_game_purchases
  purchases.merge(Game.unlimited)
end
```

which uses [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) to merge the condition of both queries

---

By the way, there is of course a way to create another association with the same model, if as you say the seller also has a `has_many :unlimited_games` already working, then your association will look like:

```
has_many :unlimited_game_purchases, trough: :unlimited_games, source: :game
```

You can choose the way you understand better